# python class: questions about creating instances

Tags: python, class

I am using python 2.7 and I want to create some kind of data structure, using classes

**Question A:**

Let's say that I create this class:

```
class my_data():
   def __init__(self,data1,data2,data3):
      self.data1 = data1
      self.data2 = data2
      self.data3 = data3
```

and after that I create some instances of the class, e.g.

```
d1 = my_data(1,2,None)
d2 = my_data(4,5,d1)
d3 = my_data(7,8,d2)
```

As you see, data3 may be None or an instance. So far so good.

Now, let's once more try to create some other instances (the hard way):

```
d2 = my_data(4,5,d1)
d1 = my_data(1,2,None)
d3 = my_data(7,8,d2)
```

In this case NameError Exception will occur, because obviously in line
d2 = my_data(4,5,d1), d1 has not been defined.

So, here is the question: I want to create instances in which data3 should be None or an instance. 
If data3 is None or an existed instance, no problem.
But if data3 refers to an unexisted instance, I want that instance to be created.

For example: d2 = my_data(4,5,d1)

if d1 does not exist, I want to be initiated as a dummy instance d1 = my_data(None,None,None), and after that, d2 to be initiated as well

I tried this but doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
class my_data():
   def __init__(self,data1,data2,data3):
      self.data1 = data1
      self.data2 = data2
      try:
         self.data3 = data3
      except:
         data3 = my_data(None,None,None)
     self.data3 = data3
```

**Question B:**

Let's say that somehow we have created some instances (d1,d2,d3,...) of the class. How can I store the instances in a list inside the class, so every instance which has been created in this class to be included in the list?

something like my_data.my_list()
which will produce
[d1, d2, d3, ...]

Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: The `my_data` constructor is not passed the name `d1`. It is passed the object that the variable `d1` refers to. If `d1` does not refer to anything, the `NameError` occurs before the constructor can do anything about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot materialize an object from a non-existing reference. Python names *have* to exist for them to work.

Instead, give the `data3` keyword a default, then when the keyword is **not** specified, create the instance:

```
_sentinel = object()

class my_data():
   def __init__(self, data1, data2, data3=_sentinel):
      if data3 is _sentinel:
          data3 = my_data(None, None, None)

      self.data1 = data1
      self.data2 = data2
      self.data3 = data3
```

Now you can create instances of `my_data()` with a default new instance for `data3`:

```
>>> d2 = my_data('a', 'b')
>>> d1 = d2.data3
>>> d1
<__main__.my_data instance at 0x10e994cf8>
>>> vars(d2), vars(d1)
({'data1': 'a', 'data3': <__main__.my_data instance at 0x10e994cf8>, 'data2': 'b'}, {'data1': None, 'data3': None, 'data2': None})
```

Because we used a sentinel default value, you can still set `data3` to `None` as well:

```
>>> d3 = my_data('a', 'b', None)
>>> d3.data3 is None
True
```

A mutable list on the class can hold all instances; just set the list as a class attribute and append new instances to that:

```
_sentinel = object()

class my_data():
   instances = []

   def __init__(self, data1, data2, data3=_sentinel):
      if data3 is _sentinel:
          data3 = my_data(None, None, None)

      self.data1 = data1
      self.data2 = data2
      self.data3 = data3

      my_data.instances.append(self)
```

and you can list all instances with `my_data.instances`.

Do note that this creates circular references, keeping instances alive even when you no longer use them anywhere else. Use the [`weakref` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) if you want to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever think about redesign your data structure and object? create a instance of object A inside object A is not a good approach. Maybe you should divide the my_data into two objects. one holds the two values, the other holds the relatioinships and the list.

PS: I strongly suspect you are representing graphs using my_data, if so try **Networkx**, a good packages for graph stuffs.

Comment: Actually I do want to use networkx in order to represent a hydraulic network, consisted of pipes.Each pipe sould be a node, connected with other pipes via edges.Every object pipe sould be like pipe(ID,length,flow,parent).The main goal is to find a clever way to insert randomly sorted data from a txt file:
ID_1,length_1,flow_1,parent_1(integer,float,float,integer or string)
ID_2,length_2,flow_2,parent_2
(each group represents a pipe)
... somehow convert parent_1,parent_2,... from integers to object pipes and finaly constract with all the data a tree under networkx